# Unzipping and extracting file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to unzip a file and transfer the contents into a mongodb collection using R. To unzip and extract the file i'm using this line:

`jFile = zip.file.extract(students.json, zipname = "students.zip", unzip = getOption("unzip"))`

But it keeps giving this error:

`Error in zip.file.extract(students.json, zipname = "students.zip", unzip = getOption("unzip")) : could not find function "zip.file.extract"`

and i have no idea why.

Comment: Not sure about your error, but I have used `unzip()` from the `utils` package in R and it is pretty simple and straight forward. If you cannot debug that, I would give `unzip()` a try

Comment: Thank you. ```unzip()``` is far more staightfoward.